# Why do I get error underline in vscode even though its a working php code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

[image]

How do i fix the error on my vscode even though its a PHP file and PHP code that is just fine

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the lines, what does it say?

Comment: Line indented incorrectly; expected at least 12 spaces, found 3phpcs
Line indented incorrectly; expected at least 12 spaces, found 3phpcs
Undefined function 'do_action'.intelephense(1010)
Call to unknown function: 'do_action'PHP(PHP0417)
No quick fixes available

Comment: Select the code, or the whole page and press the following buttons: On Windows Shift + Alt + F
On Mac Shift + Option + F
On Ubuntu Ctrl + Shift + I
This will automatically sort the content you have selected to the vscode extension's needs. You might have changed the intellisense for your php extension which gives this "error", although it's more a warning than an error.
About the do_action error it could be that it is not defined yet or linked correctly, but since I only have a screenshot and not any source code I cannot help you with that

Comment: hmm i tried it still does give the red underlines

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "<?php" is missing on the line.

Comment: wich line doyou mean ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).